# Loading fixtures with Karma

Tags: fixtures, karma-runner

The files attribute in my config file for Karma is

```
files: [
            // Program files
            'public/js/init.js',

            // Load mocks directly from bower
            'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',

            // Fixtures
            {
                pattern: 'test/fixtures/*.json',
                watched: true,
                served: true,
                included: false
            },

            // Specs
            'test/unit/**/*.spec.*'
        ]
```

And one of fixtures is as follow: test/fixtures/languages.json

```
{
    "ab":{
        "name":"Abkhaz",
        "nativeName":"аҧсуа"
    },
    "aa":{
        "name":"Afar",
        "nativeName":"Afaraf"
    },
    "af":{
        "name":"Afrikaans",
        "nativeName":"Afrikaans"
    }
}
```

How could I load the json mentioned above in a variable in a expect statement?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it manually with ajax, or you can use karma with requirejs and a requirejs json file loader plugin...

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', '/base/test/fixtures/languages.json', false);
xhr.send();
console.log(xhr.status, xhr.responseText); //200, {...}
```

Karma runs in the browser, so you can do everything with karma, what you can do normally in a browser... If you want to use generated information from server side, be aware that karma does have an own server, so your tests run under different domain, and you should use CORS to get the data from your application server. By client side static files this should not cause a problem if you register their patterns in your karma config file...